# Why use OOP concept? What are the usages of OOP?

Tags: oop

Why do we use OOPs concepts? 
What are the advantages/disadvantages of OOP?
Where do we use OOP?
How do we tell if a program can be written in OOP paradigm? How is it organized?

Note : I'm not related to technical field... So please consider this in your answers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to summarize very broad, technical subjects in a few paragraphs that the layman can understand.

Comment: You might find more people willing to answer your question on www.reddit.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: to reduce the cognitive load required to write, maintain and understand the software.

Software systems are inherently complex, so developers need some tools to break things down to the modules and individual components that could be analyzed and understood without enormous efforts — and OOP is just that kind of tool.

Answer (score 0):

Thats quite a big question. And I try to give you a feeling why we do develop principals like oop ,soa,....

Most of the principal target to make software less complex. Imagine a file with 1.000.000 functions. it would become difficult to find the you want to change. Especially if there are not veryx wqell name like "Update" so you could have a thousand "update" methods.

Often things are less complex if you don't see the complete information pool so you can focus and things you may need. Thats also why there ideas like the [information hiding principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) .

Another thing is that when you have **standards** you have to think about. For example in Real life you know that you can sit on a chair (thats a standard) you don't ahve to think about it. Thats why standards make like easier. Some aspects of OOP establish standards (e.g. use of classes) therefore there is little less complexity.

Having class which are grouping the functions may be the first step towards oop. Now when you search a function you would most propably know what you want to udpat "a custoemr" so you know this function may be in the customer class and you have to only look over these methods.

And most of the time thats what principals are made for. making software more read and understandable

OOP is much much more and not the only paradigm .But there is so much more and OOP has so much principals and **interprations**. It would be too much to explaind and discuss it here. I would also recommend you to have a look at the *CleanCoders Movement* which provide this in a more general way.

- [CleanCoders Webcasts](http://cleancoders.com/)
- [Does ORganization matter](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2015/04/15/does-organization-matter.html)